# Find element in one array that's in another array unequal lengths JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm coming from Python learning JavaScript.  In Python, to find out if an item in one list is in another list, I can do something like:

```
haystack = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
needle = ['a', 'b', 'e']

[i for i in haystack if i in needle]
```

In JavaScript, it seems the length of the list matters, as the code below returns `ab` rather than `abe`:

```
var needle = ["a", "b", "e"]
var haystack  = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

var found = "";
for (i=0; i < haystack.length; i++){
  for (j=0; j < needle.length;j++){
    if (needle[i] === haystack[j]) {
      found+=needle[j]
      }
    }
  }
console.log(found);
```

Python doesn't seem to care if the lists are of unequal lengths but JavaScript does.  How can I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the total right idea- the problem is that your if statement is backwards, so it's not iterating through each element in haystack.

```
if (haystack[i] === needle[j]) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
var needle = ["a", "b", "e"]
var haystack  = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
var list = needle.filter(word => haystack.indexOf(word) >= 0);
```

Here in this solution you don't have to iterate over length of the array explicitly. And it returns an array of filtered words.

Other choices

```
var list = needle.filter(word => haystack.includes(word));
```

The second one being not supported in IE.

You have done the indexing wrong

```
if (needle[i] === haystack[j])
```

will be

```
if (needle[j] === haystack[i])
```

And also instead of adding those strings into the array you have formed another string by concatenating them.

Comment: You could also use `haystack.includes(word)` since you don't care about the index

Comment: @RobM.: That's a nice way.

Comment: Actually, I'd put it back... `includes` is not supported in IE at all, so `indexOf` is more broadly applicable.

Comment: Nice compromise :D

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice since it is a) a good approach and b) basically what's happening in the Python code, so a good translation

Comment: This achieves the require result, but it doesn't tell the OP what was wrong with their code.

Comment: @RobG.: Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Length does not matter, you loop through both lists. You just made a little mistake on

```
if (needle[i] === haystack[j]) {
  found+=needle[j]
  }
```

Since you loop through haystack using `i` and needle using `j`. When you use `haystack[j]` instead of `haystack[i]` your if clause only goes up to `"c"` on haystack It should've been:

```
if (needle[j] === haystack[i]) {
  found+=needle[j]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```js
function inArray(v, a){
  for(i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    if(a[i] === v){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function needlesInHaystack(needlesArray, haystackArray){
  for(var i=0,n,a=[],l=needlesArray.length; i<l; i++){
    n = needlesArray[i];
    if(inArray(n, haystackArray))a.push(n);
  }
  return a;
}
var needles = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'g'], haystack = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
console.log(needlesInHaystack(needles, haystack).join(''));
```